Is the identity element well-defined?
I was trying to find an identity element of the following structure:

Set: $S =\{ (k/2) + 1\mid k\in\Bbb Z\}$
Operation: $a*b = 2ab - 2a - 2b + 3$.

Identity element, when calculated, is $3/2$, which belongs to $S$.
This was the process:
$a*e = e*a = a$ (operation is commutative)
$a*e = a$
$2ae - 2a - 2e + 3 = a$
When solving this I had to divide both sides of the equation by $2a-2$, meaning $a$ can't be $1$. But number $1$ belongs to $S$. So, does this mean that I can't divide by $2a-2$, therefore I don't have an identity element?
I tried to solve $a*e$ for $a=1$ and $e=3/2$ and I got $0 = 0$.
I'm stuck here because our professor didn't mention what to do if we have a condition that's not true for every element of the set.

You don’t need the +1. Also if $ 1 \ast e =1$ you win you confuse implication and equivalence

Not sure how division enters into it.  If $b=\frac 32$ then $a\ast b = a \ast \frac 32=3a-2a-3+3=a$ regardless of the value of $a$.  Are you looking for inverse elements?  That's a different question, of course.

@julio_es_sui_glace if you're reffering to (k/2 + 1) it was a part of the task, but I didn't use it here anyway, just on the end to check if identity element belongs to the set

@lulu I added a photo for context on the equation. The task was to define which structure is (S,*) so finding the identity element is just one part of it

Again, $\frac 32$ is an identity element.  No division involved.  I think, but am not sure, that you are asking a different question (like the existence of inverses) but it's far from clear.

"and I got 0=0."  which... is true... so you haven't solved for $e$ but you haven't gotten a contradiction either.  In this case that means any value (including $\frac 32$) will result in $1*b = 1$.   So if $a=1$ then every element satisfies the condition.  If $a \ne 1$ then only $\frac 32$ satisfies the condition.

For ordinary multiplication, we have that $1$ is an identity element.  But, $a\times 0 =0$ for any $a$.  so, the situation you describe is perfectly familiar.

When you try to solve you must do two cases
Cast 1:  $a \ne 1$ then $a*e= a \implies 2ae -2a -2e +3 =a \implies a =\frac 32$.
Case 2: $a =1$ then $1*e = 1\implies e\cdot (2a-2) = 3a-3\implies e\cdot 0 = 0$ can be satisfied for any value of $e$.
Combining the two possible solutions we must have  1) $e=\frac 32$ and 2) $e\in S$ .  The combination is .... $e=\frac 32$.  No contradiction or weird things.
You had to divide to solve for $e$ but that's only to figure out what $e$ can be in the first place.  You never have to divide to use $e$ and as $1\cdot \frac 32=1$  (in fact $1*b = 1$ no matter what $b$ is) everything is fine.

You are looking for some $e\in S$ such that $$\forall a\in S\quad2ae - 2a - 2e + 3 = a$$
i.e.
$$\forall a\in S\quad(a-1)(2e-3)=0.$$
Since this equation is satisfied for any $e\in S$ when $a=1$, what you want is some $e\in S$ which satisfies it also $\forall a\in S\setminus\{1\}$, whence the answer $e=\frac32$ (which belongs indeed to $S$).
